# get product attribute by product attribute group in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

How to get product **attribute group** in magento 2 from a **attribute set**. I want to show attribute on **listing page** by using a group so i can add more attributes in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you simply get all product attribute by `$product->getAttributes();`

```
$productAttributes=$product->getAttributes();
        $group_id=9;
        $attributeSetId=4;
        foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute) {
            if ($attribute->isInGroup($attributeSetId, $group_id)) {
             echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel().' : '.$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product).'<br />';
            }

    }
```

Comment: @QaisarSqatti how can i identify the group id here any help or which table shoul i search fot it?

Comment: Got it in `eav_attribute_group` table. but there are many entries for product details group.

Comment: @NitinPawar `<?php 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance(); 
$productCollection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\Collection');
$productCollection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 $productCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',4)
->addAttributeToSort('attribute_set_id', 'asc');

$productCollection->load();
foreach ($productCollection as $key => $value) {
    echo '<pre>';  print_r($value->getData());
}` you can get group information from following collection

Comment: I managed to get the group id from attribute set id and group name but i can't get the attribute from the group id. Please check my question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/147302/magento-2-check-the-attribute-is-in-specific-group-or-not

Comment: @Qaisar Satti , I have put this code to grouped.phtml file but not working.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `getAttributeGroupId` method:

*vendor/magento/module-catalog/Model/Config.php*

```
public function getAttributeGroupId($attributeSetId, $name)
{
   ......     
}
```

We can get attribute group id:

```
   $obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Config $config */
    $config= $obj->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Config');

    $attributeGroupId = $config->getAttributeGroupId(1, 'General');
```

Should take a look `eav_attribute_group`.