# Magento 2: Check the attribute is in specific group or not

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

Hi i am trying to get the attributes of product from specific group.  I am using following code.

```
$pattr = $product_coll->getAttributeSetId();
$group_id = $block->getAttributeGroupId($pattr);
$attrCodes = $block->getProductAttrData($pattr);
foreach($attrCodes as $attrCode)
{
    echo $attrCode->getDefaultFrontendLabel().'<br>';
    if ($attrCode->isInGroup($pattr, $group_id))
    {
        echo 'In Product details';
    }       
 }
```

I write this code in my phtml template. But this is not working. Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you tried this is tested code

```
$productAttributes=$product->getAttributes();
      foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute):
        if ($attribute->isInGroup($pattr, $group_id)):
            if($attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product_coll)):
                echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel().' : '.$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product_coll).'<br />';
            endif;
         endif;
      endforeach;
```

Comment: did you load all attributes of product?

Comment: Yes it loads and shows the attribute label as i updated in the question

Comment: `$groupCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name','Testing');` can you check the attribute group id is correct?

Comment: I cross checked the group id in database `eav_attribute_group` table. It is correct.

Comment: @NitinPawar let me test a get back to you

Comment: @NitinPawar use `$productAttributes=$product->getAttributes();`  to get all attribute not `$attrCodes = $block->getProductAttrData($pattr);` then function will run `isInGroup`

Comment: $group_id = $block->getAttributeGroupId($pattr); there should be foreach for group_id as product attribute set has multiple group

Comment: how to get specif group all attributes ?

Comment: Did anyone get this to work? I'm trying to only display product attributes in tab from a certain group. I'm able to get the attribute set id and group id, but loop does not find any matches.