# Magento 2 : Get Product Attribute values By Group

Tags: magento2, product, attributes

I would like to show the various attributes divided into groups as created in the set of attributes, such as

- general

  - attribute_label1 :attribute_value1
  - attribute_labe2 :attribute_value2
  - ...
- other info

  - attribute_label1 :attribute_value1
  - attribute_labe2 :attribute_value2
  - ...

How do I retrieve the attribute groups and their labels?

or is there a module to do this?
I have override theme and change `catalog_product_view.xml` file

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="catalog.product.specification" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/specification.phtml" after="catalog.product.extra.info"/>
```

And wants collection within this file `specification.phtml`

Comment: similar question asked here  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/134179/get-product-attribute-by-product-attribute-group-in-magento-2

Comment: It is not dynamic.I wants dynamic thats why.I want to list all attribute product group wise there are multiple group and have multiple attribute assign to this,also think about multiple attribute set

Comment: I did in mag1 but in mag2 little hard

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `catalog_product_view.xml` change to:

```
<block class="Custom\Module\Block\Product\Specification" name="catalog.product.specification" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/specification.phtml" after="catalog.product.extra.info"/>
```

File **app/code/Custom/Module/Block/Product/Specification.php**

```
<?php
namespace Custom\Module\Block\Product;

class Specification extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View
{
     /**
      * @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory
      */
     protected $groupCollectionFactory;

     public function __construct(
         \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
         \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
         \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
         \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
         \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
         \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
         \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
         \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
         \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
         \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory,
         array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $urlEncoder, $jsonEncoder, $string,
        $productHelper, $productTypeConfig, $localeFormat, $customerSession,
        $productRepository, $priceCurrency, $data);
        $this->groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory;
    }


    public function getAttributeLabels()
     {
    $product = $this->getProduct();

    $attributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();

    $groupCollection = $this->groupCollectionFactory->create()
        ->setAttributeSetFilter($attributeSetId)
        ->setSortOrder()
        ->load();

    $html = '';
    foreach ($groupCollection as $group) {
        $attributes = $product->getAttributes($group->getId(), true);



        $new_html = "";
        foreach ($attributes as $key => $attribute) {
            if($attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) !="" && $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) !="Non"){

                $new_html .= '<td class="td-full">
                                <table>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th class="even">' . $attribute->getFrontend()->getLabel(). '</th>
                                            <td class="evev-1">' . $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product) . '</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>                 
                            </td>';

            }
        }

        if($new_html!=''){

            $html .= '<h3>' . $group->getData('attribute_group_name').'</h3>';
            $html .= "<table>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>";
            $html .= $new_html;
            $html .= "</tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>";
        }

    }

    return $html;
}
}
```

And in `specification.phtml` you can call it

```
<?php echo $block->getAttributeLabels() ?>
```

Comment: Notice: Undefined property: Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Interceptor::$groupCollectionFactory--->I have called View for get product on view page how can i sove that?

Comment: You should DI $groupCollectionFactory as instance of \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory in your class

Comment: Please can you edit your answer with my requirement?Thanks

Comment: @KetanKpBorada I've updated my answer.

Comment: Waw Exact Solution !!Yet i've edit this as I don't need attribute which is not allowed on product page and also not display group which has not attribute

Comment: @KetanBorada Thanks a lot for this code, works perfect. The only problem we face is that it does not show the right store label of the attribute. We need the frontend store label in the right language. The attribute value is displayed well in the right language. How to achieve this?

Comment: @HenkZ use `$attribute->getStoreLabel()` for store label

Comment: Do you know how to do same for API?

Comment: I want to list Attribute Groupwise in admin https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5588

Comment: @QuanLe Do you know how to implement this also for the product compare page?